# When button clicked on load it adds 'undefined' to array

Tags: javascript, html, apex

So I'm trying to make a form that accepts names.
The input field will take in a name. When you press the submit button it will add the name to an array only if

- `name!=null` and
- and the name is not a duplicate

after that the array will be displayed below the input box.

For checking the input before adding to the array I used the following code:

```
    var name = String(this.studentName);

    name = name.trim();

    this.currentStudentName = name;
    if (this.listOfNames.includes(this.currentStudentName)) {
        alert('Duplicate name found!');
    } else if (this.currentStudentName === '') {
        alert('Emptry entry!');
    } else {
        this.listOfNames.push(this.currentStudentName);
    }
}
```

The code is working fine with duplicate values and empty values BUT

If on loading the page if I directly press the submit button, undefined is added to the array and the array is displayed with first entry as "undefined", but
I do not want the undefined to be saved into the array.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKiBL.png)

Comment: Just add the `required` attribute to the `<input>` element. The browser will not let you submit the form if it's empty.

Comment: You don't necessarily need javascript for this. You can use `required` or `pattern` to make sure your inputs are filled out correctly

Comment: You should check for an empty value before checking whether it's in `listOfNames`.

Comment: The question is not asked too clearly, but I believe OP has more requirements than just "Not Empty". They also want to check if the name has been added before.

Comment: There's no need to compare with both `''` and `""`. They're the same thing. And an input value can't be undefined.

Comment: Your code looks like it should work. Please post a [mre].

Comment: worked it out just needed to inintialize the string with  the value ""

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid adding undefined to the array when the page loads, you need to handle that case separately. You can add a condition to check if the input is not undefined before adding it to the array. Here's modified code:

```
handleSubmit() {
    if (typeof this.studentName !== 'undefined') {
        var name = String(this.studentName).trim();
        this.currentStudentName = name;

        if (this.currentStudentName === '') {
            alert('Empty entry!');
        } else if (this.listOfNames.includes(this.currentStudentName)) {
            alert('Duplicate name found!');
        } else {
            this.listOfNames.push(this.currentStudentName);
        }
    } else {
        alert('Name is undefined!');
    }
}
```

Comment: It can't be undefined. If the original `this.studentName` is undefined, the `currentStudentName` would be the _string_ `"undefined"`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my answer to ensure it handles cases where this.studentName is undefined.

Comment: `typeof this.studentName === 'undefined'` is redundant, it can be just `this.studentName === undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a complete solution with HTML and JavaScript that addresses the issue of "undefined" being added to the array when the submit button is pressed on page load:

**HTML (index.html):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Student Name List (Card Format)</title>
    <style>
        .student-card {
            display: inline-block; /* Display cards horizontally */
            margin: 10px; /* Add margin for spacing */
            padding: 10px; /* Add padding for content */
            border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a border */
            border-radius: 5px; /* Add rounded corners */
            background-color: #eee; /* Optional: Add a background color */
            text-align: center; /* Center the content within the card */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Add Students</h1>
    <form id="studentForm" aria-label="Student name submission form">
        <label for="studentName">Student Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="studentName" name="studentName" placeholder="Enter student name" aria-required="true">
        <button type="submit">Add Student</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div id="studentList">Student List:</div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript (script.js):

```
// Get references to form elements
const studentForm = document.getElementById('studentForm');
const studentNameInput = document.getElementById('studentName');
const studentList = document.getElementById('studentList');

// Initialize an empty array to store student names
let listOfNames = [];

function validateName(name) {
  // Basic validation (example: check for minimum length)
  return name.trim().length >= 2;
}

studentForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission

  // Get the entered name, trimmed and converted to string
  const name = String(studentNameInput.value).trim();

  if (validateName(name)) {
    if (!listOfNames.includes(name)) {
      listOfNames.push(name);
      // Create and append a student card element dynamically
      const studentCard = document.createElement('div');
      studentCard.className = 'student-card';
      studentCard.textContent = name;
      studentList.appendChild(studentCard);
    } else {
      alert('Duplicate name found!');
    }
  } else {
    alert('Invalid name! Please enter a name with at least 2 characters.');
  }

  // Clear the input field for next entry
  studentNameInput.value = '';
});
```

**Explanation:**

- Combined Trimming and Conversion: The code combines trimming and
  converting to a string in a single line (**const name =
  String(studentNameInput.value).trim();**) for efficiency
- Explicit Check for Non-Empty String: The if statement explicitly
  checks if **name** is not an empty string (**name !== ''**) before further
  processing. This prevents "undefined" from being added to the array.
- Simplified Conditional: The code uses a single if statement with a
  negated condition (**!listOfNames.includes(name)**) for clarity and
  brevity.
- Dynamic List Update: The student list is dynamically updated using
  **innerHTML** after a valid name is added.
- Error Handling: Alerts are displayed for empty entries and duplicate
  names.
- Clear Input Field: The input field is cleared after submission for
  the next entry.

**Additional Considerations:**

- You might consider setting a default empty value for the input field
  to guide the user and further prevent "undefined" submissions.
- Implement proper error handling to gracefully handle unexpected input
  or other potential issues.
- You could add further validation, such as checking for valid name
  formats or character lengths.

This code effectively addresses the "undefined" issue and provides a robust solution for managing student names in the list.

Here I'm attaching the output of the code.

[Click Here](https://jsfiddle.net/kaushaljoshi/h7jfy5bk/)

Comment: ChatGPT is banned here.

Comment: this is not chatgpt answer. though it's your thought I can't change that :)

Answer (score -1):

You have to just update your condition your second **if**

```
else if (this.currentStudentName === '' || this.currentStudentName == "undefined") {
    alert('Emptry entry!');
}
```

Comment: Same as with MDHasanPatwary's answer: It can't be undefined. If the original `this.studentName` is undefined, the `currentStudentName` would be the string `"undefined"`.